# Two relationship columns are generated for one 1:n relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to model a simple 1:n relationship using Fluent NHibernate:
There are persons and items. One person has zero to infinite items while one item belongs to one person.

My data classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }
}
```

and the mappings:

```
public sealed class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Owner);
    }
}
public sealed class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.Items).Inverse();
    }
}
```

My problem arises when I try to create the database schema using NHibernate's `SchemaExport` class.

The Item table actually gets two columns referencing the Person table:

```
create table [Item] (
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
   Owner_id INT null,
   Person_id INT null,
   primary key (Id)
)
```

Why is that?
One column should be enough - as far as I understood, the call to `Inverse` should supress the second column - however, it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is wrong - the call to `Inverse` tells NH the relationship is managed from the other side (i.e. you'll be adding items by setting the `Owner`); it doesn't change anything about schema generation.

I don't know the exact Fluent syntax, but essentially you need to tell it that the key column for the `HasMany` is `Owner_id`.

Answer (score 1):

The mapping for `Person` should be:

```
public sealed class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.Items)
            .KeyColumn("Owner_id")
            .Inverse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - is there any alternative which works without the "magic string" constant?

Comment: @winSharp93 "Magic string" is not what you think it is. But use a `const` if you want

Comment: With "Magic String" I mean a string constant in code that can be easily forgotten to change as it references another part of the code (in this case the value of String depends on the Name of the "Owner" Property). Thus, introducing a constant wouldn't change much IMHO. What is a "magic string" according to your definition? Or what do you think that I think that a magic string is? ;-)

Would it generally considered a best practice to generally specify all Column names in the mapping files then?